# Export to excel multiple sheet/tab in salesforce apex

Tags: salesforce, export-to-excel, apex, visualforce

I want to Implement export to excel functionality in salesforce apex with Visual force page. I want to export to excel with multiple sheet/tabs. Sheet/tab would be dynamic. There are multiple datatable/grid is available I have to export each data table to different sheet. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with Javascript, you can write your logic and queries in Apex and call those methods from the browser, feeding the data into some xlsx package.

SheetsJS has a handy method called [json_to_sheet](https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs#array-of-objects-input) that you can use to populate the data into a sheet/tab. Then you can add the sheet(s) to a excel document and initiate a browser download. There are example in the documentation.